# Artifactory Unable to find module with librarian-puppet

Tags: puppet, artifactory, librarian-puppet, pdk

I'm trying to use the librarian-puppet to fetch forge modules from an Artifactory repository.

In my Puppetfile I have something like:

```
forge "https://<artifactory_host>/artifactory/api/puppet/<repo_key>" #From artifactory docs

# PuppetLabs Modules
mod 'puppetlabs/stdlib',           '4.24.0'
```

The command that I'm using is `/usr/local/bin/pdk bundle -- exec librarian-puppet install --no-use-v1-api --verbose`

The error that I get is:

```
[Librarian] Resolving puppetlabs-stdlib (= 4.24.0) <https://<artifactory_host>/artifactory/api/puppet/<repo_key>>
[Librarian]   Checking manifests Unable to find module 'puppetlabs-stdlib' on https://<artifactory_host>/artifactory/api/puppet/<repo_key>
/tmp/tmp.BXyhBoNRiR/.pdk/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/librarian-puppet-3.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/source/forge/repo_v3.rb:44:in `rescue in get_module'
/tmp/tmp.BXyhBoNRiR/.pdk/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/librarian-puppet-3.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/source/forge/repo_v3.rb:41:in `get_module'
```

Versions:

- puppet 3.8.7
- pdk 1.5.0
- ruby 2.1.9

According to the documentation at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Puppet+Repositories#PuppetRepositories-Usinglibrarian-puppet, it seems I'm trying to get the modules correctly using the librarian-puppet, but something most be missing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I think Artifacotry does not support Puppet 3.8.7 its documented in Wiki.

Puppet version support

Puppet does not support a context path up to version 4.9.1, we recommend using Artifactory with Puppet version 4.9.2 and above. Please see below if you are using Puppet 4.9.1 and below.

Comment: Hi Jainish. Thanks for the response. In this case changing the puppet version is not an option. This means that using the librarian-puppet is not possible? The goal is to use the Puppetfile and get the modules from an internal Artifactory repository.

Comment: You can use Nginx to rewrite URL. As documented in the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

[The official Artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Puppet+Repositories) (not a wiki) recommends using Puppet 4.9.2 or later with Artifactory:

> **Puppet version support**
>
> Puppet does not support a context path up to version 4.9.1, we
>   recommend using Artifactory with Puppet version **4.9.2** and above.
>   Please see below if you are using Puppet 4.9.1 and below.

(Emphasis in the original.)

As that comment indicates, however, the docs do also suggest [a workaround for use with earlier Puppet](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Puppet+Repositories#PuppetRepositories-UsingPuppet4.9.1andBelow):

> If you need to use Puppet 4.9.1 and below you can use a workaround
>   which uses NGINX or Apache to rewrite all requests from `/v3/*` to
>   `/artifactory/api/puppet/<repo-name>/v3/*`.

The docs go on to present some example configurations, which I will not repeat here.